# Patch or software to replace the ugly Windows clock?

Tags: windows-8

I would like to replace the clock that appears in the bottom right corner of windows 8 with a better looking one. Could you recommend any software, or add-on that I could use? Thanks

edit:
The clock I want to change is the one on the Windows taskbar at the bottom of the screen (see picture).

[image: example]

### Other details:

The replacement software can be both free or commercial (free a plus).

As far as the aesthetics is concerned, I am open to any alternative to this one, no specific preference.

Comment: Please add more details: free/gratis or commercial? What does a "better" clock need to look like? You know, aesthetics is a matter of opinion, so maybe you give us an example clock image you like

Comment: @Thomas please see the edit

Comment: On Windows 7, you can at least turn it off: right click the clock, "customize notification icons", "Turn system icons on or off", Clock: off

Comment: @Thomas On Windows 8 you can hide it too, however I risk to loose touch with the world without a clock on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Anuko World Clock](https://www.anuko.com/world_clock/):

- Commercial license, 25 USD
- Replaces the Windows clock
- adjustable background color
- support for skins, even analog clocks are possible
- support for several clocks in different time zones

Comment: This seems a good alternative although a little pricey, I'll keep the question open for other alternatives a few days and if nothing pops up I'll definitely accept it. Thanks

Comment: @mickkk: that's totally fine. I'd appreciate if someone knows a free alternative.